# Как послать post запрос с csrf токеном

Tags: python, django, requests

Хочу послать post запрос на свой сайт на `django`, что бы добавить комментарий, для этого нужен `csrf token`. Вроде в `headers` я его и добавляю, но мой сервер отвечает `Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /product/azregmgzczfspbesz`. `requests` отдает ошибку `403` То есть мой запрос просто отклонен.

Код запроса

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/azregmgzczfspbesz'

def main():

    client = requests.session()
    client.get(url)

    if 'csrftoken' in client.cookies:
        csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
    else:
        csrftoken = client.cookies['csrf']

    data = dict(content="testreq")
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0',
               'Cookie': f'csrftoken={csrftoken}; sessionid=2bfxxgv499y88yqh8bj0qhtgv1s1di9j'}
    res = requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers=headers)
    print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Форма `html`:

```
        <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <textarea type="text" name="content" cols="60" rows="12" maxlength="5000" required id="id_content">
                </textarea><br>

                <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Так надо не в headers, а в data, на что намекает строчка `{% csrf_token %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете **Django ≥ 4**, то теперь необходимо указывать **CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS** в **settings.py**:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://your-domain.com', 'https://www.your-domain.com']
```

См. [документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#csrf-trusted-origins-changes-4-0).